# Split delimited values in excel using jupyter python

Tags: python, excel, split, jupyter

here is a string that is stored in an excel cell:

```
100.42.7.8
```

I just wonder how I could split it into 4 parts and print as following:

```
100
42
7
8
```

currently I am using python (xlsx) in jupyter and I do know how to use `sheet.cell.value[:3]` to get the first 3 characters. But just wonder if there is any function for `sheet.cell.value` that involves the delimiter (dot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
print ' '.join(sheet.cell.value.split('.'))
```

Check built-in [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) functions.

Comment: i tried by clicking on the upward point arrow but seems like it only counts once i have earned 15 reputation. but thx for the help!

Comment: i c!  i just clicked on it. sorry m new here.